# Mysql case to inner join and select data

Tags: mysql

I want to check what is in column `TTo` and as the value select from different tables and must inner join that table

mysql5

```sql
SELECT note.*,
(CASE
 WHEN TTo=0 THEN teacher.Name 
 WHEN TTo=2 THEN parent.Name
 WHEN TTo=3 THEN student.Name
 ELSE teacher.Name
END)
FROM note 
INNER JOIN 
(CASE
 WHEN TTo=0 THEN teacher ON teacher.ID=note.IDTo
 WHEN TTo=2 THEN parent ON parent.ID=note.IDTo
 WHEN TTo=3 THEN student ON student.ID=note.IDTo
 ELSE teacher
END)
WHERE TFrom=2 AND IDFrom=1
```

Comment: This schema is a nightmare to work with. I would change it.

Comment: switch to a stored procedure there you can build your query.

Comment: No. Just fix your schema